# Flutter- Since adding Cloud Messaging Android app crashes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ever since I added cloud messaging to my Flutter app, the app crashes on load.

It works fine on iOS.

As far as I can tell its all set up properly, and the fact that It works on iOS I am at a loss..

This is the logcat file

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:78)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:71)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:468)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:354)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-06-05 13:02:06.390 7346-7346/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 24 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/org.heartchurch.heartland-M4kZV3m1AevnHc2GxsBI5A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
2019-06-05 13:02:06.391 7346-7346/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
                ... 8 more
```

I have made sure the following is added to my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the android project.

Go the build.gradle of firebase_messaging

In the dependencies change `api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'` to 
        `api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'`

Make sure you are using the latest version of all the cloud dependencies in pubspec.yaml

This solution worked for me